# How to add class to the dynamically creating element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here in below code I'm creating a tag based on the element. Now, I want to add class to the element. How I can add.

```
if((t.elementName==="pre" || t.elementName==="PRE") || 
(t.elementName==="code" || t.elementName==="CODE")){
  return g1 + '<' +t.elementName+ '>' + g2 + '</' + t.elementName + '>';
   }
```

Here I want to add class how I Can Add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   return g1 + '<' +t.elementName+ ' class="'+className+'">' + g2 + '</' + t.elementName + '>';
```

Or if you know class name (class name is static):

```
 return g1 + '<' +t.elementName+ ' class="myclassName">' + g2 + '</' + t.elementName + '>';
```

Comment: Thanks. Working fine.